# Arduino IDE gives library compilation error for Nodemcu

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, esp-12f

I need to calculate Matrix Determinant for my project. Of all the ones I've found, this is the best working library.
When I test it with Arduino Mega 2560 it compiles and the codes work fine. But when I try to compile for Nodemcu 1.0 (ESP12E) it gives the attached* error

Library link: https://github.com/TheForeignMan/ArduinoMatrixLibrary

*Error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.19 (Windows Store 1.8.57.0) (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled (new aborts on oom), Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 32KB cache + 32KB IRAM (balanced), Use pgm_read macros for IRAM/PROGMEM, 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"


C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware -hardware C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages -tools C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=esp8266:esp8266:nodemcuv2:xtal=80,vt=flash,exception=disabled,stacksmash=disabled,ssl=all,mmu=3232,non32xfer=fast,eesz=4M2M,led=2,ip=lm2f,dbg=Disabled,lvl=None____,wipe=none,baud=115200 -ide-version=10819 -build-path C:\Users\Artemis\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_329065 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Artemis\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_463768 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.python3.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\python3\3.7.2-post1 -prefs=runtime.tools.python3-3.7.2-post1.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\python3\3.7.2-post1 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\mkspiffs\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs-3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\mkspiffs\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\mklittlefs\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs-3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\mklittlefs\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc-3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -verbose C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\BasicMatrixAlgebra\BasicMatrixAlgebra.ino

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware -hardware C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages -tools C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=esp8266:esp8266:nodemcuv2:xtal=80,vt=flash,exception=disabled,stacksmash=disabled,ssl=all,mmu=3232,non32xfer=fast,eesz=4M2M,led=2,ip=lm2f,dbg=Disabled,lvl=None____,wipe=none,baud=115200 -ide-version=10819 -build-path C:\Users\Artemis\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_329065 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Artemis\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_463768 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.python3.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\python3\3.7.2-post1 -prefs=runtime.tools.python3-3.7.2-post1.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\python3\3.7.2-post1 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\mkspiffs\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs-3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\mkspiffs\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\mklittlefs\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs-3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\mklittlefs\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc-3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed.path=C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed -verbose C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\BasicMatrixAlgebra\BasicMatrixAlgebra.ino

Using board 'nodemcuv2' from platform in folder: C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.2

Using core 'esp8266' from platform in folder: C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.2

Detecting libraries used...

"C:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065/core" -c -w -Werror=return-type -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -w -x c++ -E -CC -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10819 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -DESP8266 "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\cores\\esp8266" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\variants\\nodemcu" "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065\\sketch\\BasicMatrixAlgebra.ino.cpp" -o nul

Alternatives for MatrixLibrary.h: [ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master]

ResolveLibrary(MatrixLibrary.h)

  -> candidates: [ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master]

"C:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065/core" -c -w -Werror=return-type -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -w -x c++ -E -CC -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10819 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -DESP8266 "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\cores\\esp8266" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\variants\\nodemcu" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master" "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065\\sketch\\BasicMatrixAlgebra.ino.cpp" -o nul

"C:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065/core" -c -w -Werror=return-type -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -w -x c++ -E -CC -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10819 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -DESP8266 "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\cores\\esp8266" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\variants\\nodemcu" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master" "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\\MatrixLibrary.cpp" -o nul

Generating function prototypes...

"C:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065/core" -c -w -Werror=return-type -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -w -x c++ -E -CC -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10819 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -DESP8266 "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\cores\\esp8266" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\variants\\nodemcu" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master" "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065\\sketch\\BasicMatrixAlgebra.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"

"C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\tools-builder\\ctags\\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"

Compiling sketch...

"C:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\python3\\3.7.2-post1/python3" -I "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/signing.py" --mode header --publickey "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\Arduino\\BasicMatrixAlgebra/public.key" --out "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065/core/Updater_Signing.h"

"C:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065/core" -c -w -Werror=return-type -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10819 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -DESP8266 "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\cores\\esp8266" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\variants\\nodemcu" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master" "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065\\sketch\\BasicMatrixAlgebra.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065\\sketch\\BasicMatrixAlgebra.ino.cpp.o"

Compiling libraries...

Compiling library "ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master"

"C:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\\3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065/core" -c -w -Werror=return-type -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10819 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -DESP8266 "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\cores\\esp8266" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\ArduinoData\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\3.0.2\\variants\\nodemcu" "-IC:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master" "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\\MatrixLibrary.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\Artemis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_329065\\libraries\\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\\MatrixLibrary.cpp.o"

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp: In constructor 'Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix*)':

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:35:21: error: passing 'const Matrix' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

   35 |  Zeros(matrix->Rows(), matrix->Columns());

      |                     ^

In file included from C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:27:

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master/MatrixLibrary.h:50:6: note:   in call to 'int Matrix::Rows()'

   50 |  int Rows();

      |      ^~~~

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:35:40: error: passing 'const Matrix' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

   35 |  Zeros(matrix->Rows(), matrix->Columns());

      |                                        ^

In file included from C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:27:

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master/MatrixLibrary.h:51:6: note:   in call to 'int Matrix::Columns()'

   51 |  int Columns();

      |      ^~~~~~~

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:40:78: error: passing 'const Matrix' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

   40 |    SetValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex, matrix->GetValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex));

      |                                                                              ^

In file included from C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:27:

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master/MatrixLibrary.h:54:9: note:   in call to 'double Matrix::GetValueAt(int, int)'

   54 |  double GetValueAt(int row, int col);

      |         ^~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp: At global scope:

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:47:1: error: default argument given for parameter 3 of 'Matrix::Matrix(int, int, double)' [-fpermissive]

   47 | Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols, double initialValue = 0.0)

      | ^~~~~~

In file included from C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:27:

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master/MatrixLibrary.h:42:2: note: previous specification in 'Matrix::Matrix(int, int, double)' here

   42 |  Matrix(int rows, int cols, double initialValue = 0.0);

      |  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:55:1: error: default argument given for parameter 2 of 'Matrix::Matrix(int, bool)' [-fpermissive]

   55 | Matrix::Matrix(int squareSize, bool isIdentityMatrix = false)

      | ^~~~~~

In file included from C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:27:

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master/MatrixLibrary.h:43:2: note: previous specification in 'Matrix::Matrix(int, bool)' here

   43 |  Matrix(int squareSize, bool isIdentityMatrix = false);

      |  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:73:8: error: default argument given for parameter 3 of 'Matrix Matrix::NewMatrix(int, int, double)' [-fpermissive]

   73 | Matrix Matrix::NewMatrix(int rows, int cols, double initialValue = 0.0)

      |        ^~~~~~

In file included from C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:27:

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master/MatrixLibrary.h:45:9: note: previous specification in 'Matrix Matrix::NewMatrix(int, int, double)' here

   45 |  Matrix NewMatrix(int rows, int cols, double initialValue = 0.0);

      |         ^~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp: In member function 'Matrix Matrix::NewMatrix(int, int, double)':

C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master\MatrixLibrary.cpp:75:24: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'double*' [-fpermissive]

   75 |     thisMatrix = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(double));

      |                  ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      |                        |

      |                        void*

Using library ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master in folder: C:\Users\Artemis\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoMatrixLibrary-master (legacy)

exit status 1

Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

Test Code:

```
#include <MatrixLibrary.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("myMatrix:");
  Matrix myMatrix(2, 2);
  myMatrix.SetValueAt(0,0,2.67);
  myMatrix.SetValueAt(0,1,5.66);
//  myMatrix.SetValueAt(0,2,3.95);
  myMatrix.SetValueAt(1,0,1.22);
  myMatrix.SetValueAt(1,1,5.54);
//  myMatrix.SetValueAt(1,2,9.12);
//  myMatrix.SetValueAt(2,0,8.98);
//  myMatrix.SetValueAt(2,1,7.99);
//  myMatrix.SetValueAt(2,2,5.56);
  myMatrix.PrintMatrix();

  Serial.println("DET(myMatrix):");
  Serial.println(myMatrix.Determinant());
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("END");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: The Xtensa gcc is v10.3 and is applying C++17 rules.  What version/standard is used for AVR builds?

Comment: The errors you're seeing are mostly down to "`const` correctness" issues. E.g.  the `int Rows()` function should be `const` qualified so that it could be legally called on `matrix` inside  `Matrix(const Matrix* matrix);`. The reason why it "works" on AVR is that that core supplies `-fpermissive`.  Also there's a lack of explicit cast in the `malloc` call needed in C++.  I started to write a length answer on how to fix it, but really the library is horribly broken in a few ways. E.g. it never `free`s what it `malloc`s. It never checks to see that `malloc` succeeded. Find a different library.